# How to correctly link button by ids in Kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I want to add buttons to boxlayout, but there is some issues in my code. When i click the add button or remove button i receive AttributeError message.
Thanks for helping me.

My python code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager


class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Hello'

    def add_more(self):
        print('test')
        addbutton = self.root.ids.abc
        addbutton.add_widget(Button(text='hello'))

    def remove(self):
        print('test')
        if len(self.root.ids.abc.children) > 0:
            self.root.ids.abc.remove_widget(self.root.ids.abc.children[0])



if __name__=='__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

My kv code:

```
#: import SwapTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.SwapTransition

ScreenManagement:
    transition: SwapTransition()
    MainScreen:
    SecondScreen:



<MainScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        id:aaa
        Button:
            text: 'Add'
            on_press: app.add_more()

        Button:
            text:'Remove'
            on_press: app.remove()
        BoxLayout:
            id:abc


<SecondScreen>:
```

AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem - AttributeError

```
     addbutton = self.root.ids.abc
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 843, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

## Root Cause

There is no `id: abc` in the root which is a `ScreenManager`.

## Solution

There are two options to the solution.

### Option 1 - using get_screen()

In this option, we retrieve the instantiated object, `MainScreen:` using [`get_screen()`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager.current_screen) function so that we can access its method(s) or attributes e.g. `id: abc`. We will make the following enhancements:

#### kv file:

- We [name](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.Screen.name) the screens, `name: 'MainScreen'` and `name: 'SecondScreen'` for instantiated objects, `MainScreen:` and `SecondScreen:` respectively.

**Snippets - kv file**

```
ScreenManagement:
    transition: SwapTransition()
    MainScreen:
        name: 'MainScreen'
    SecondScreen:
        name: 'SecondScreen'
```

#### Py file

- Retrieve the instantiated object, `MainScreen` using [`get_screen()`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager.current_screen) function

**Snippets - Py file**

```
def add_more(self):
    print('test')
    addbutton = self.root.get_screen('MainScreen').ids.abc
    addbutton.add_widget(Button(text='hello'))

def remove(self):
    print('test')
    container = self.root.get_screen('MainScreen').ids.abc
    if len(container.children) > 0:
        container.remove_widget(container.children[0])
```

### Option 2 - using id: mainscreen

In this option, we add `id: mainscreen` to instantiated object, `MainScreen:` and use `ids.mainscreen` to access its method(s) or attributes e.g. `id: abc`. We will make the following enhancements:

#### kv file:

- Add `id: mainscreen` to instantiated object, `MainScreen:`

**Snippets - kv file**

```
ScreenManagement:
    transition: SwapTransition()
    MainScreen:
        id: mainscreen
    SecondScreen:
```

#### Py file

- Replace `self.root.ids.abc` with `self.root.ids.mainscreen.ids.abc`

**Snippets - Py file**

```
def add_more(self):
    print('test')
    addbutton = self.root.ids.mainscreen.ids.abc
    addbutton.add_widget(Button(text='hello'))

def remove(self):
    print('test')
    container = self.root.ids.mainscreen.ids.abc
    if len(container.children) > 0:
        container.remove_widget(container.children[0])
```